# Synchronizing users between two identical Windows 2008 R2 instances (second one is XenConvert clone)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, synchronization, user-accounts

I'm running IIS 7 server where users are using dedicated application pools so I need for all of them separate users. I'm moving my environment to XenServer and I'm using for this XenConvert tool. Everything is fine except that I need to synchronize Windows local users between this two Windows instances. I don't have problems with files and their permissions since I use for it robocopy.

Any idea how to just copy users between this two Windows systems?

Regards

EDIT: users are local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this software solved my problems:

http://www.winzero.ca/ServerMigrator.html

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear if these servers are domain joined or not but I'm going to guess they aren't.  Microsoft has a tool to copy users between boxes but it can't copy the password.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;250267

You may need to just recreate the accounts on the new server and reconfigure the application pools.

EDIT: Windows Server Migration Tools should work.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379531(WS.10).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379545(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_full

Comment: Users are local but my system is Windows 2008 R2 (x64) Web Server. Your link points to tool which was available in Windows 2000 and NT.

Comment: Edited answer with something that should work for your OS.  My mistake for not checking applicability of the first link.

Comment: Server migration tools as far I can see are not available for WebServer Windows 2008 R2 edition :/

Comment: arg...I'm all out of ideas then.  Looks like you'll have to create the accounts manually.